# Why is my path to my image not working in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, path

Here's my folder layout

```
src                                   (folder)
   images                             (folder)
         alligators                   (folder)
                  Alligator 1.svg     (svg file)
   main.js                            (javascript file)
```

And here's my line of code in main.js file:

```
    <img src={require("./images/alligators/Alligator 1.svg")} alt="alligator illustrator" />
```

I am getting no errors, I'm just getting my alt-text displayed and my image not being shown.

What seems to be my problem with my path?

I also just tried {} curly without "require", but the result is the same. I tried renaming Alligator 1 without a space, but again, the result is the same.

If my code is correct, what other possible reasons could this be happening?

Comment: What happens when you change `require` to `import`?  If that doesn't work, add `import alligator from './images/alligators/Alligator 1.svg'` at the top of your file and changing your code to `src={alligator}`.

Comment: @squillman thanks, the manual `import alligator from 'path'` works and then changing it to `src={alligator}`, but the require->import didn't do anything. I'm not sure why the manual import works but not the image one since it's the same exact path

Comment: to try  <img src="./images/alligators/Alligator 1.svg" alt="alligator illustrator" /> its work for me. and do not like the space into file name.

Comment: @romanown doesn't work. it works when i'm in my html/css files but not in react, no clue why. and it's the same path, give or take a slight syntax difference

Comment: this is because You have shown the directory structure and use it when designing. and the images should be placed in the structure that is obtained after compiling. where the resulting bundle is. the link to which is located in the html file. but it is still more convenient for you to probably do as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to import the image and then use it in the src like this:

```
import alligator from './images/alligators/Alligator 1.svg';
...
<img src={alligator} alt="alligator illustrator" />
```

With the import your file gets stored into `alligator` and is then available for React to use.  React then resolves it in your img tag.

Answer (score 0):

in react.js, you can put your images inside of the public folder (the same directory as src), and then just serve it with it's default path, e.i :`src="/image.svg"`

Comment: Yea, but I'd like to keep my files organized instead of having a bunch in the SRC folder.